# How do I whitelist everything I need for BootstrapVue to work with Purgecss in Nuxt.js

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-4, nuxt.js, bootstrap-vue

I have created a Nuxt.js project which uses BootstrapVue for the UI. In order to reduce the bundle size I import only the BV components that I need on a per component basis. However, I was still ending up with an excessively large bundle because bootstrap.css and bootstrap-vue.css were being bundled in their entirety. bootstrap.css being the main problem in terms of size.

In an attempt to solve this, I installed nuxt-purgecss in the hope that it would extract all unused css from bootstrap.css, and bootstrap-vue.css, and create versions for the bundle that only includes css for the BootsrapVue classes that I am actually using.

At first, neither file was getting bundled at all, and after some searching, I found that the solution appeared to be whitelisting the BootstrapVue selectors that I'm using. (Although I would love it if someone could show me a way that I didn't need to do that and purgecss could evaluate it on its own!)

The relevant parts of nuxt.config.js are now as follows:

```
  modules: [
    'nuxt-purgecss'
  ],
  purgeCSS: {
    mode: 'postcss',
    paths: [
      'components/**/*.vue',
      'layouts/**/*.vue',
      'pages/**/*.vue',
      'plugins/**/*.js',
      'node_modules/bootstrap-vue/es/**/**/*.js',
      'node_modules/bootstrap-vue/**/*.js'
    ],
    styleExtensions: ['.css'],
    whitelist: [
      'html',
      'body',
      'navbar',
      'nuxt-progress',
      'b-navbar',
      'b-navbar-toggle',
      'b-navbar-brand',
      'b-navbar-nav',
      'b-nav-item',
      'b-alert',
      'b-collapse',
      'b-nav-item-dropdown',
      'b-dropdown-item',
      'b-container',
      'b-row',
      'b-col',
      'b-card',
      'b-form',
      'b-form-group',
      'b-form-input',
      'b-button',
      'b-modal'
    ],
    whitelistPatterns: [/^b-/, /nav/]
  },
  build: {
    /*
     ** You can extend webpack config here
     */
    extractCSS: true, // TODO: Necessary?
    extend(config, ctx) {
      // if (ctx.isDev) {
      //   config.devtool = ctx.isClient ? 'source-map' : 'inline-source-map'
      // }
      config.devtool = 'source-map'
    }
  }
```

Having completed the above, I find that my built solution is rendering nearly as expected, but I am having several issues I cannot fathom:

```
<template>
  <b-navbar
    sticky
    toggleable="md"
    type="dark"
    variant="dark"
  >
    <b-navbar-toggle target="nav_collapse"></b-navbar-toggle>
    <b-navbar-brand to="/">Application</b-navbar-brand>
    <b-collapse id="nav_collapse" is-nav>
      <b-navbar-nav class="ml-auto mr-4">
        <auth-nav-item />
      </b-navbar-nav>
    </b-collapse>
  </b-navbar>
</template>
```

This renders, but type and variant are not taking effect, i.e. it should be white text on a black background bar but is actually white on white (so effectively invisible to a user.) I can fix this by applying a local style, but I really would like to understand what I need to do to get this to function as intended.

I have a similar situation with a b-alert which has a white background regardless of the the variant attribute.

The other weird one is that `<b-col md="5">` is being respected unless there is a b-alert within the col. If there is, it expands left and right further than it should.

I'm guessing that there are some extra things I need to whitelist, but so far, I'm struggling to understand what they are. If anyone can tell me, I'll be eternally grateful!!!

(Also, as I mentioned earlier, if there was a way of configuring this so purgecss automatically knows what is there without having to tell it, that would be even better!)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Bootstrap v4.3.x CSS doesn't play well with PurgeCSS (actually purgeCSS doesn't play well with Bootstrap CSS), as many of the classes needed depend on the values of the various props. PurgeCSS makes educated guesses, but it doesn't always make the correct guess.

Your best bet is to not use PurgeCSS, and instead use the Bootstrap SCSS source files, and only include the sections (files) of bootstrap v4.3 SCSS that you are using (it is relatively modular, although it can be a bit confusing).

See:

- https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/getting-started/theming/#importing
- https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/reference/theming

Comment: Thank you so much Troy! That has put me back on track!

Comment: I have added the bootstrap modules separately and set purgecss ignore around the imports in the custom.scss file. It works in local dev mode, however in production all the bootstrap styles get removed. Could you elaborate on how to 'whitelist' all imported bootstrap files and why it works in dev, but not in production? Thank you in advance!

Comment: In production mode, everything goes through minifiers, which typically remove comments.

Comment: Have struggle with this for a very long time... but nothing really changed and improved. Hopefully next version of BootstrapVue will help a bit with the tree-shaking of JS & CSS ;)